# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loading properties from both file and database

Tags: spring, properties, placeholder

I'm wondering if its possible to load properties from both file and database, and use the properties in file when loading properties in database. So what I want to achieve is to save app properties in the database, and save the database info in the properties file. Below is my configuration, but it didn't work, the value in jdbc.properties cannot be loaded before reading database properties. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
    <property name="locations">  
        <list>  
            <value>classpath*:jdbc.properties</value> <!--loading properties from file first-->
        </list>  
    </property>  
    <property name="properties"  ref="dataBaseProperties"/> <!--loading properties from database using the properties from file-->
</bean>

<bean id="dataBaseProperties" class="common.spring.DatabaseProperties" >  
    <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="confDataSource"/>  
    <constructor-arg value="select key_s,value_s from app_conf where status>0"/>  
</bean>

<bean id="confDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"/> <!--from properties file - jdbc.properties-->
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/> <!--from properties file - jdbc.properties-->
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/> <!--from properties file - jdbc.properties-->
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/> <!--from properties file - jdbc.properties-->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> <beans:bean id="appProperties"
> class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
>       <beans:property name="location"
> value="classpath:META-INF/application.properties" />  </beans:bean>
```

You should mention the location from where it fetches the *.properties file

Comment: I am getting the same result.

Comment: <beans:bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
        <beans:property name="properties" ref="dataBaseProperties"/>
    </beans:bean>

Comment: Remove that ref bean

Comment: @Jonny where have placed the jdbc.properties file by the way

Comment: the location is 'WEB-INF\classes\jdbc.properties'

Comment: If I remove the ref bean, then how to load the properties in database?